# How to construct depencies for pdf files with no Maven conform filenames

Tags: gradle, dependencies

I have an Artifactory repository in which, in addition to other Maven-compliant deployed jar files, there are also PDF files that have not been loaded into the Artifactory in a Maven-compliant manner.

Example: For a fictitious module xxx, I have the following files in my artifactory location:
myRepository/at/mic/xxx/at.mic.xxx.doc/8.1.0/: MIC-XXX_User_Guide_de.pdf, MIC-XXX_User_Guide_en.pdf
Although the file names of the two PDF files are different, they have the same Maven coordinates: group: 'at.mic.xxx', name: 'at.mic.xxx.doc', version: '8.1.0', ext: '.pdf'

I have tried this dependency definition for this purpose:

```
repositories {
  ivy {
    url <https://"myRepository">
    patternLayout {
      artifact "[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact].[ext]"
      m2compatible = true
  }
  metadataSources {
    artifact()
  }
}
dependencies {
  implementation(group: "at.mic.xxx", name: "at.mic.xxx.doc", version: "8.1.0", 
                  changing: true) {
    artifact {
      name = 'MIC-XXX_User_Guide_de' 
      extension = 'pdf'
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, this dependency definition gives me this error:

```
> Could not find MIC-XXX_User_Guide_de-8.1.0.pdf (at.mic.xxx:at.mic.xxx.doc:8.1.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         myRepository/at/mic/xxx/at.mic.xxx.doc/8.1.0/MIC-XXX_User_Guide_de-8.1.0.pdf
```

When resolving the dependencies, Gradle expects my PDF files to contain the version at the end of the file name (typical for Maven).

Do you have any advice on what I need to change so that Gradle tries to download MIC-XXX_User_Guide_de.pdf instead of MIC-XXX_User_Guide_de-8.1.0.pdf?

Thanks in advance!
Frank

Comment: I don't believe it's possible to try and access these files using the Gradle repositories mechanism. That mechanism looks for the POM/XML metadata files present in Maven/Ivy repos, which don't seem to be present here. (See https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#sec:repository-types). Unfortunately, I'd be falling back to using regular http.